# android custom lint codeInspection not work in Library

Tags: lint, code-inspection

I custom a lintCheckrule，but codeInstpection just work in application module

[image: code in application module show codeInspection]

same code in Library do not show codeInspection.

[image: same code in Library module not show codeInpection]

Comment: but lint task work well，the wrong code in Library appear in lint report ，Only codeInpection not show in the code 。who can tell me why？